# Change .htaccess to 301 Redirect and REMOVE wildcard category from URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I've got a large wordpress site that has been using the permalink structure of http://[root]/[category]/[postname] for the last 6 years and now I'd like to change it to remove the category part of the URL.

I can do this easily but obviously I will then have a problem with Search Engines sending people to the incorrect address so I want to add a line in my .htaccess to 301 redirect people to the new path without the category.

However the category is dynamic AND it mustn't changed the URL if the URL has the following terms in it

(image, images, wp-content, wp-admin, wp-includes)

I'd like the list to be in an array so I can add to it if I find other names that mustn't change.

So as an example

http://www.lazygamer.net/sony/sonys-trying-trademark-lets-plays/

should become

http://www.lazygamer.net/sonys-trying-trademark-lets-plays/

but

http://www.lazygamer.net/images/2014/07/Lets-play-a-game_thumb.jpg

must not change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those urls including "image", "images", "wp-content" etc. are actual files or directories on the server, you can exclude them form the rewrite rule for the dynamic content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/?$ /$2/ [r=301,nc,L]
```

Comment: so the line RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/?$ /$2/ [r=301,nc,L] will remove the category in the URL? Could you explain what it is doing a little?

Comment: It will match any url with /[any text without a forward slash]/[any text without a forward slash #2] . This is very broad, so you may have to tweak it if it conflicts with any other rules. It will then redirect 301 to /[any text without a forward slash #2]/

e.g.

/mycat/some-news-article will redirect to /some-news-article

The rules for that line [r=301,nc,L] means:

issue 301 redirect
nc=no case
L=last rule to apply

You will obviously need to ensure WordPress handles the new urls, and that you place this new rewrite logic in the correct place of your htaccess if there's other rules.